# Formatting a decimal from SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm stuck here trying to format a decimal value from a MSSQL server. The value in MSSQL is like this: `0.40860000000000000000` and I need the value to be like this in C#: `40.86000`

Does anyone know how to format it like this? Have searched high and low, but haven't found a working example yet :-(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you gather that number? where you need that number formatted? in your code? on a form? in a custom control? please post some code

Comment: A you performing a Unit Conversion on this Value?

Comment: Hiya, the 0.4086000000 value is from a Navision database :-) I need to format it like the example I wrote in my console application.

Comment: How are you outputting it at the moment? Have you tried `String.Format(...)`?

Comment: do you just want to display it to within a certain decimal place?

Comment: Dmitrys answer made it work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just *format* the value out? E.g. if you need *6 digits after decimal poin*t you can put it like that

```
   Decimal d = 0.40860000000000000000M; 
   // Or
   // Double d = 0.40860000000000000000; 
   String result = (d * 100).ToString("F6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to :-) Thanks a lot Dmitry !

Comment: Bo, it is customary on SO to accept an answer when it helped you, or pointed you in the right direction. I know Dmitry got a lot of points, but still. Good manners man

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Round:

```
Decimal number = 0.40860000000000000000; // number you want to round 
int x = 6;; // number of decimal places to be rounded to

var rounded = Decimal.Round(number, x, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round(v=vs.110).aspx

If you only want to display it to a certain number of decimal places, you can use `.ToString()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx

Comment: Didn't quite cut it :-/ the output is still with a leading zero :-)